# No further traces reported after timeout exception

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-gcp

I integrated spring-cloud-sleuth with GCP support into an application. Under load the app suddenly stops reporting any spans until it is restarted.

The only tracing relevant log i can see is the following exception:

```
Unexpected error flushing spans java.lang.IllegalStateException: timeout waiting for onClose. timeoutMs=5000, resultSet=false
     at zipkin2.reporter.stackdriver.internal.AwaitableUnaryClientCallListener.await(AwaitableUnaryClientCallListener.java:49)
     at zipkin2.reporter.stackdriver.internal.UnaryClientCall.doExecute(UnaryClientCall.java:50)
     at zipkin2.Call$Base.execute(Call.java:380)
     at zipkin2.Call$Mapping.doExecute(Call.java:237) at zipkin2.Call$Base.execute(Call.java:380)
     at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:285)
     at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$Flusher.run(AsyncReporter.java:354)
     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This exception happens a few times around the time the traces end and then never aggain (as if something permanently breaks)

I read in a spring-cloud-gcp issue (see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1617)) that this can be related to to few executer threads so i already configured the number of threads to 8 (from 4).